# Math Random sin que se repitan mis combinaciones de numeros

Tags: javascript, random

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un programa en js donde los números random del array que voy repitiendo no se repitan en cada lineal, cada lineal debe contener 6 números aleatorios.
He estado buscando información pero no se muy bien como sería.

```js
let min = 1;
let max = 49;

let loteria = [
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
];

function aleatorio(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

console.log('****Loteria****');
for (let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
    if (loteria[i] != undefined) {
      console.log(loteria);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Solo debes comprobar si el numero generado ya existe dentro de tu array, si no existe, pues lo ingresas

Comment: como se haría esto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar algo como esto, quizá es mejor realizarlo en un while

```js
let min = 1, max = 49;

function aleatorio(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function getLoteria(){
  let valores = [];
  while(valores.length < 6){
    const value = aleatorio(min, max);
    if (valores.indexOf(value) < 0) valores.push(value);
  }
  return valores;
}

console.log('****Loteria****');
for(let i=0;i<50;i++){
  const loteria = getLoteria();
  console.log(loteria);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero algo así ya habia conseguido, es que yo necesito sacar 6 numeros por linea y deben de ser diferentes a la linea inferior

Comment: @azucarilla y cuantas lineas necesitas crear? se puede hacer lo mismo y dividir el arreglo con `slice()`

Comment: Necesito mostrar 50 lineas con 6 numeros cada una, eso si lo consigo pero en cada linea las posiciones corresponden al mismo numero, y deberían ser diferentes, por ejemplo linea1: 1,2,3,4,5,6   linea2:4,67,2,3,5,34   linea3: 9,10,11,12,13,14 y asi con las 50 lineas sin repetir ninguna de las lineas

Comment: @azucarilla lo edité para generar 50 lineas. Saludos

Comment: disculpa que sea pesada, pero basandome en mi codigo como sería esto ? Estoy tratando de ubicar tu respuesta con mi codigo pero no termino de entender muy bien

Comment: @azucarilla lo edite para poder usar valores enteros, ademas que como mencionaste, hice que se pudieran repetir los valores en la loteria

Comment: en mi código creo que ya se repetian cierto? es que debo hacerlo lo mas similar a como lo haría yo ya que debo entregarlo a un profesor, solo me falta la parte de no repetir en mi codigo pero no logro entenderlo. disculpa.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115879/discussion-between-julio-javier-and-azucarilla).