# JS como hacer que math random muestre los numeros sin decimales

Tags: javascript, random

Hola estoy tratando de enseñar un numero aleatorio en JS, de forma que salga el numero entero sin decimales, pero el math random me lo enseña con decimales, hay alguna forma de que salga sin?

```js
let min = 1;
let max = 49;

let loteria = [
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
];

function aleatorio(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
    if (loteria[i] != undefined) {
      console.log(loteria);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilziar `math.Round()`, mira la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

```js
let min = 1;
let max = 49;

let loteria = [
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
];

function aleatorio(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
    if (loteria[i] != undefined) {
      console.log(loteria);
    }
  }
}
```

También puedes usar `Math.floor` y `Math.ceil`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! No sabia del math.round

Comment: Con gusto, si la solución te funciona recuerda marcarla como respuesta para que los demás usuarios del sitio logren encontrar respuestas a sus preguntas.

Comment: me faltaban 9 minutos jajajajajaja igualmente ahora en un ratito la marco como resuelta gracias!!

Comment: @azucarilla en la otra respuesta igual estaba con `Math.round`  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/404235/155064

Answer (score 2):

También puedes usar la doble negación binaria para hacer el redondeo, básicamente estás haciendo la conversión a entero de manera implícita

```js
let min = 1;
let max = 49;

let loteria = [
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
  aleatorio(min, max),
];

function aleatorio(min, max) {
  return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
    if (loteria[i] != undefined) {
      console.log(loteria);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wau!!! Gracias desconocia esto

Comment: Monstruosa y limpia la solución, para mi la mejor, crack

Comment: :0 No sabía que se podía hacer eso. ¿Tiene algún drawback? He estado investigando un poco, pero no encuentro nada contundente

Comment: @FranAcuna la legibilidad, no es tan claro para un novato lo que se está haciendo